# Augmented Dickey-Fuller test interpretation before and after log transform the data

Tags: r, interpretation, stationarity, logarithm, augmented-dickey-fuller

I have apply the stationarity test to a stock's adjusted price by using the Augmented Dickey Fuller Test with the program R.

That is the output from `adf.test(df, alternative = 'stationary')`:

```
    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  df
Dickey-Fuller = -2.7776, Lag order = 13, p-value = 0.2491
alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

Then I calculate log returns `log_returns <- periodReturn(df, period='daily', type='log'); adf.test(log_returns, alternative = 'stationary')`, I get:

```
p-value smaller than printed p-value
    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  log_returns
Dickey-Fuller = -13.224, Lag order = 13, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

Do the results above mean that the data is stationary after log transform? 
Some one could help me interprete the results before and after log transformation? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tseries)
adf.test(df, alternative = 'stationary')
```

Out:

```
    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  df
Dickey-Fuller = -2.7776, Lag order = 13, p-value = 0.2491
alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

We fail to reject the null hypothesis that timeseries is nonstationary and conclude that the time series has a unit root.

```
log_returns <- periodReturn(df, period='daily', type='log')
adf.test(log_returns, alternative = 'stationary')
```

Out:

```
p-value smaller than printed p-value
    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  log_returns
Dickey-Fuller = -13.224, Lag order = 13, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

We reject the null hypothesis that this time serries is non stationary and we conclude the the differenced log transformed times serries is stationary.